# Dual boot windows 8.1 acer V3-571G with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to dual boot my acer which came with  windows 8 pre-installed.

I tried using the tutorial [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/)  doing it the simple way but when I load Ubuntu from my transcended flash drive it says that there is no other operating system installed.

I tried partitioning my hard drive but I seem to have 3 recovery partitions and even though I have 485GB free I can only allocate 100GB to the new partition.

I would like to have most of my hard drive allocated to Ubuntu and just use the windows for programs like microsoft office.

Comment: where did you try partitioning,in windows or ubuntu-live disk?